# URL in "@odata.nextLink" for https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/{chat-id}/messages resulting in 400 Bad Request or a valid response randomly

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

The Microsoft Graph API seemingly randomly responds with either a `400 Bad Request` or a valid response when requesting the second page results using the `@odata.nextLink` URL included in the initial response to `/chats/{chat-id}/messages`

Originally I thought this issue was with our Microsoft Graph Java SDK usage, but I can reproduce it with `curl`. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
TOKEN="{token-contents}"

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/19:3300a88fbed249d38e8beb6c32d86a07@thread.v2/messages"

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/19:3300a88fbed249d38e8beb6c32d86a07@thread.v2/messages?\$skiptoken=U291cm...{omitted skip token contents}"
```

Response from initial request to `/chat/{chat-id}/messages`:

```
{
   "@odata.context" : "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#chats('19%3A3300a88fbed249d38e8beb6c32d86a07%40thread.v2')/messages",
   "@odata.count" : 4,
   "@odata.nextLink" : "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/19:3300a88fbed249d38e8beb6c32d86a07@thread.v2/messages?$skiptoken=U291cm...{omitted skip token contents}",
   "value" : [ 
      {... message contents}
   ]   
}
```

Response from `chats/{chat-id}/messages?\$skiptoken={skiptoken}`:

```
{
   "error" : {
      "code" : "BadRequest",
      "innerError" : {
         "client-request-id" : "ecec426d-95b3-4110-bfb9-1af4a5c00192",
         "date" : "2022-01-13T19:17:34",
         "request-id" : "ecec426d-95b3-4110-bfb9-1af4a5c00192"
      },
      "message" : "Bad Request"
   }
}
```

Make the **exact same request** a second later and I get a valid response:

```
{
   "@odata.context" : "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#chats('19%3A3300a88fbed249d38e8beb6c32d86a07%40thread.v2')/messages",
   "@odata.count" : 0,
   "value" : []
}
```

If I make this request repeatedly, it'll fail some of the time and pass some of the time. There doesn't seem to be any pattern.

From curl's verbose output: the ids of the `400 Bad Request` response where:

```
< request-id: ecec426d-95b3-4110-bfb9-1af4a5c00192
< client-request-id: ecec426d-95b3-4110-bfb9-1af4a5c00192
```

And the ids of the valid response where:

```
< request-id: 9dadbce8-60ee-4dd4-a53c-37b2c967cfb3
< client-request-id: 9dadbce8-60ee-4dd4-a53c-37b2c967cfb3
```

Comment: I noticed this issue was referenced (and apparently fixed) in this github issue:https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/9729

Comment: I cross posted this question to the existing Microsoft graph docs issues post: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/15479